How can I include a project's folder structure in my dbt Cloud project's DAG?
I'm looking for a way to include folder structure and other available metadata into my dbt Cloud project's DAG. While the lineage is clearly demonstrated in the DAG generated, I'm looking for a way to visibly group staging models that come from a single source or even add tags to my DAG. For example, I know that the nodes can be either green for sources or blue for models, but I would want the staging models from a single source to be visibly grouped together, or even having a tag such as "finance" appear within the node.
Is this at all possible with dbt Cloud (a confirmation that it isn't possible is equally helpful)?

I do not believe that this is possible with dbt Cloud currently
